# Why is my drain circuit always drawing current, regardless of MOSFET gate state?

Tags: microcontroller, led, mosfet

I'm building a circuit that will drive various 12V solenoids and a pump.  I use an [MDF1903 MOSFET](http://www.magnachip.com/product/down.php?filename=MDF1903.pdf) to switch the pump and a ULN2003A to drive the various low-power solenoids.  A micro-controller signals the MOSFET and transistors accordingly.

In order to simulate the 12V components, I've replaced them with 2V LEDs and appropriate resistors to limit current at 12V.  This works fine for the LEDs switched under the transistors, however I've noticed that the LED switched by the MOSFET is always on (albeit at low intensity).  Why is this?  Shouldn't this only occur when the gate voltage is high?  The program on the micro-controller initializes the output pin to the low state and the output pin is grounded with a 10K pull-down resistor.

Here is a simplified circuit to illustrate my dilemma.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWuE1l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For what its worth, the ground inputs and outputs on my Buck converter are common.  The LED draws the full 20mA in its "on" state, and only 0.9mA in its "off" state.  I also measured 10V across drain and source/ground, which is the 12V supply less the 2V dropped from the active LED.  Regardless, I'm a bit confused as to why there is any current draw at all.  Have I done something wrong, or am I thinking about this too hard?

Comment: Sounds like a damaged FET.  ESD damage to the gate oxide can cause it to behave like this.

Comment: Disconnect the Gate from the MCU, leaving just the 10 k to ground. If the LED is still on (even dimly) you have a damaged FET. If the LED goes out, then you have a software problem and you are turning on the LED at a low duty cycle.

Comment: @JohnD: Honestly, I hadn't considered that possibility until now :)

Comment: @JackCreasey: Damaged FET it is -- led draws full current when the gate is disconnected.

Comment: It draws the full current when the gate is disconnected from the 10k and the mcu pin, or it still draws current with just the mcu pin disconnected and the 10k to ground installed?

Comment: @ChateauDu: The former, when the gate is disconnected from both.

Comment: @SteveGuidi Well that's not unexpected. You need to put the 10k resistor back to correctly test it. Or connect the gate directly to ground.

Comment: To clarify, I didn't remove the 10K resistor - it still pulls-down the MCU pin.  The gate connection to the MCU was disconnected, and in this case,  the led lights up fully.  When the gate is grounded, the led also lights up, albeit not as bright.

Comment: @SteveGuidi: did you accidentally swap the source and drain? That would explain why with the gate grounded the light is dimmer (But not off): the drain-body (i.e. drain-source, since body is shorted to source) diode is conducting.

Comment: I thought you might have done that which is why I asked.  If it is really really dim it could be lighting up just from leakage current through the FET.  Check the leakage current specs in the datasheet (tried to pull them up myself and couldn't) at the correct VDS with VGS = 0 and see if the amount seems plausible to light the LED up.  Better yet try to measure the current using the 510 ohm and a super precise meter (6.5 digit) and see if your result is on par with the leakage specs for the FET

Comment: @next-hack: I thought I may have done that too, and I've been checking the connections and data sheet over and over :). I'll confirm once more.

Comment: Just for fun, I moved the LED, resistor, and +12V to the source channel, and grounded the drain.  This caused the LED to again stay lit when the gate was at 0V.  However, applying a voltage caused the LED to turn off completely.  I'm certain I've not confused the drain and source terminals -- pretty sure the component is defective at this point.

Comment: For closure, my replacement MDF1903 MOSFETs arrived today and they all work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to those that provided their feedback in the comments to my question above.  I've learned a lot more about how MOSFETs work, and also got some hands-on testing experience.

I built a simple test circuit (below) to demonstrate any failure of the component.  In doing so, I removed the micro-controller and Buck converter to eliminate any bias that these components may introduce.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNVZ1h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Clearly, there should be no signal to the gate channel when the circuit is energized.  However the LED illuminates in this configuration, and becomes only slightly brighter when the push-button is closed. In the open-switch state, Vgs is ~2.5V and I don't think that can come from anywhere other than an internal short/failure.

Here's a photo of my breadboard showing an implementation of the circuit.

[image]